# Search for a keyword in 3 tables with an INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have three tables like:

- tbl_1 -> {'id'-'name'-'price'}
- tbl_2 -> {'id'-'name'-'price'}
- tbl_3 -> {'id'-'name'-'price'}

I want to search for `Keyword` in `name` field of all the three tables. How can I do it?

Comment: Ok, so you want `SELECT * FROM tbl_1 t WHERE t.name = "Keyword"`.  Just change the table name in the query for the other two tables.

Comment: Something tells me the database design of this is faulty, but with given info I have no proof.

Comment: If all 3 tables aren't related, you probably wouldn't use a join. You would probably just run 3 queries or use a union.

Comment: Three options: a) three separate queries b) a single `UNION` query (which ends up being 4 queries total) c) if they're actually all related, a single `JOIN` query.

Comment: UNION is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why having three tables with the same content? Just create one table and add another field 'description' or 'description_id'.

This should work...

```
SELECT id, name, price FROM tbl_1 WHERE name LIKE '%Keyword%'
UNION
SELECT id, name, price FROM tbl_2 WHERE name LIKE '%Keyword%'
UNION
SELECT id, name, price FROM tbl_3 WHERE name LIKE '%Keyword%'
```

Keep in mind that this will find any string in that field, if you'd like to search for exact string remove the '%'.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION to search in multiple tables and return a combined result:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `price`
FROM `tbl_1` WHERE `name` = 'keyword'
UNION
SELECT `id`, `name`, `price`
FROM `tbl_2` WHERE `name` = 'keyword'
UNION
SELECT `id`, `name`, `price`
FROM `tbl_3` WHERE `name` = 'keyword'
```